# NullPointerException in eclipse in Eclipse itself at PartServiceImpl.internalFixContext

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I have a problem about eclipse IDE, I can't open any file in my work space; if I try to open file, eclipse will alert the following error dialog

```
"An error has occurred. See error log for more details. java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

I go to see .log file in .meta at workspace and I see a paragraph in the file like this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2557-04-09 11:40:49.422
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.internalFixContext(PartServiceImpl.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3047)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$22(WorkbenchPage.java:2969)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2951)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2947)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2911)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2902)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

How can I solve this problem - any idea?

Comment: I think it may work try this, Go to C:\Users\YourcomputerName In that .android folder will be there u delete that folder and restart the eclipse.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a bug filed for `Eclipse`:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385680

You could try restarting `Eclipse`, it helped the original poster of the issue there.

Comment: YES!!! i will try to restart eclipse.After a restart all works already fine thank you.

Comment: A simple restart from menu File-> Restart solved my problem. Tks!

Answer (score 8):

Better you update your eclipse by clicking it on *help >> check for updates*, also you can start eclipse by entering command in  command prompt *eclipse -clean*.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

I have also encountered this error . Just i opened the new window ie Window -> New Window in eclipse .Then , I closed my old window. This solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks! This solution has worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

hi，that maybe the project's problem,

chose the project and setting you eclipse:

```
project -> clean...
```

Answer (score 1):

After exiting eclipse I moved .eclipse (found in the user's home directory) to .eclipse.old (just in case I may have had to undo). The error does not show up any more and my projects are working fine after restarting eclipse.

Caution: I have a simple setup and this may not be the best for environments with advanced settings.

I am posting this as a separate answer as previously listed methods did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, but only with files cloned from git that were assigned to a proprietary plugin. 
I realized that even after cloning the files from git, I needed to create a new project or import a project in eclipse and this resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution also works fine!!**
I also faced this problem for some files only in eclipse not for all the files.

When below solutions doesn't works

1. After Doing eclipse restart
2. After cleaning
3. After opening new window

**Solution:-**

1. Please take the back up of your file from your eclipse workspace
2. Delete the file from your workspace
3. Create the file with the same name and save the code from the backup file
4. Then it started working fine!!

This is working fine!!. You may try this as well.